# MinGW-Clang's libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing?

Tags: c++, mingw, clang, mingw-w64

When I try to run [rubenvb's Clang 3.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/clang-3.2-release/), I get:

> The program can't start because `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` is missing from your computer.
>   Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I can't find the DLL anywhere... what package am I missing/how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the DLL is not in the `bin` directory? It should be.

Comment: @JesseGood: Yes, it should be but it isn't. The only DLLs I see are clang.dll and LTO.dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download a gcc package also, that build of Clang doesn't come with a C++ library or anything. It was mean to be used in combination with a gcc package. From [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/clang-3.1-release/):

> Here you will find the latest Clang compiler releases. Currently, it
>   is a functional compiler for 32-bit for C and C++. **Clang is
>   currently made to function with the gcc-dw2-4.6* package.** I also
>   provide 64-bit builds, but these are only useful for C. Compiling C++
>   to 64-bit object code will result in linker errors. You can still use
>   if for its better diagnostics and static analysis. **To use it, you
>   should extract the Clang package in the same directory as the gcc-dw2
>   package, do that the ddirectories overlap. This ensures the C and C++
>   headers are found by Clang.** To use clang, just replace "gcc" with
>   "clang" and "g++" and "clang++". Clang currently imitates GCC as a
>   frontend, and all options GCC accepts, Clang accepts. Some options
>   that are unsupported by Clang are ignored. Some DLL-related issues
>   remain, reporting these (if not done so already) to me or the LLVM
>   bugtracker will help identifying and eventually fixing them.

Comment: Ah yup, downloading `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-dw2-4.6.3-2-release-win32_rubenvb` fixed it, thanks!